# NuGet package for FlowDocument .NET Core 3

Tags: nuget, .net-core-3.0

According to [this MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.flowdocument?view=netframework-4.8) `FlowDocument` is part of .NET Core 3.0 under the Namespace:
`System.Windows.Documents`.  However, I cannot find `System.Windows.Documents` NuGet package, so what is the correct NuGet package?

Sorry for the simple questions but my searching has returned nothing.

Thanks!

edit:  Yes I have "Include prerelease" checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF assemblies as part of .NET Core 3 are not distributed as NuGet dependencies.

If you want to build an assembly that depends on WPF, try using Wpf CustomControlLibrary (NET Core) project template. When you build or pack that project, it will use a new FrameworkReference to encode the fact that it needs the WPF Framework.

Here is the example of a NUSPEC that gets created on Pack:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>WpfCustomControlLibrary1</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>WpfCustomControlLibrary1</authors>
    <owners>WpfCustomControlLibrary1</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp3.0" />
    </dependencies>
    <frameworkReferences>
      <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp3.0">
        <frameworkReference name="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF" />
      </group>
    </frameworkReferences>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using it in a ControlLibary, that was my problem!